# How can I capture multiple groups, multiple times with javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code snippet aiming to extract next and last link values from github api...

```
var types = {},
    str = '<https://api.github.com/repositories/1424470/issues?access_token=f554f90b4c95c78091a4202150d4583082dab1ce&page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/repositories/1424470/issues?access_token=f554f90b4c95c78091a4202150d4583082dab1ce&page=7>; rel="last"',
    rex = /\s*<https?:\/\/api.github.com\/.+?&page=(\d+)>;\s*rel="(\w+?)"(?:,|$)/g;

// use regex replace method to capture multiple groups multiple times
str.replace(rex, function(_, page, type){
    types[type] = +page;
});

console.log(types);
// {next: 2, last: 7}
```

It is functioning correctly, but feels like a mis-use of regex replace method, where I am not returning anything, but using it only for the sake of having a callback for each match, which I use to build up an output object.

I would prefer some kind of matchAll, returning multi-dimensional array of matches, and parts.

Is there a better way to handle this case in javascript?

Comment: @hwnd what are the options?

Comment: @hwnd that looks reasonable. A bit of a pain to have to write out the logic each time. Probably good case for utility function.

Comment: What do you mean write out the logic each time?

Comment: I mean the approach looks good. I had forgotten about `regex.exec` maintaining a starting index, allowing it to be called repeatedly, which is probably the most reasonable way to do it, but for such a general functionality, I would like to just pass a string and a pattern to a utility function, and be given back a multi-dimensional array of matches.

Comment: You can easily place that into a function.

Comment: @hwnd yes - something like this: https://eval.in/410279 I think it is good approach - thanks!

Comment: Another approach, since your regexp is pretty big already, is to split the string into parts using `match` or `split`, and then further process each part. Two steps rather than one, but this may be more maintainable in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method in a loop, pushing the match results to a multi-dimensional array.

```
function find_all(re, s) {
   var types = [];
   while (m = re.exec(s)) {
        types.push([m[2], m[1]])
   }
   return types;
}

var regex = new RegExp('<https?://[^>]+page=(\\d+)>;\\s*rel="([^"]+)"', 'gi');

find_all(regex, str) //=> [ [ 'next', '2' ], [ 'last', '7' ] ]
```